# Safe? ..Using a Y USB cable to power a dash cam from 2 power sources

Tags: usb, power-supply, battery, power

I would like to power a dashcam from 2 power sources (the car cig lighter & battery pack) using a Y-USB cable (1 female - 2 male).  I would connect my dash cam to the female end.  Then plug one of the male ends to the car cig lighter and the other male end to a battery pack.

My purpose is to have power to the dash cam at all times.  I.e. when the car is on, the dash cam would draw power from the car.  And when the car is off, the dash cam would draw power from the battery pack.

Is there any danger of back feeding from the car to battery pack or visa versa - back feed from battery pack to the car? ..and cause damage?  Any comments or suggestions?

Thanks much.

Comment: "Is there any danger of back feeding from the car to battery pack" - Without analyzing the circuit for the dashcam this cannot be determined.  However, its more likely you would burn out the dash cam, by connecting it to two different power sources at the same time.

Comment: can you include a pic of the Y USB cable?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Isn't it safe to assume that the dashcam would have a current limiter?

Comment: AT Ramhound and what exactly would you analyse about the circuit that would tell you whether it has this 'capability' that you couldn't otherwise determine?

Comment: @superfry Re current, you know a device only draws the current it needs, right?

Comment: @barlop please see the amazon link.   https://www.amazon.com/Onvian-Splitter-Adapter-Charging-Syncing/dp/B01KX4TKH6/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1550620614&sr=8-5&keywords=2+female+to+1+male+y+usb+cable

Comment: @superfry I haven't used that,, but continuing from what I said re current, what you mustn't do is plug a device that requires > x amps, into a supply that is rated for x amps. So the amps of the power source has to be >= the amps of the device.

Comment: @barlop ..yes, I thought that a device (such as a dashcam) would only draw the current it needs so that's why I thought it would be safe for the dashcam.  But was unsure of the safety of the car or the battery pack.

Comment: @superfry ANY device, not just a dashcam, will only draw the current it needs. The problem is if the current it needs is greater than the power source is rated to provide.

Comment: @superfry and by the way, that Y USB says  "only one port for data". So once you plug it into the power source, then only one of the remaining two ports is meant to be used to power a device.  I suppose that's what it means. The other port is just meant for transferring data from device's storage eg phone storage or cam storage, to computer.

Comment: @barlop actually it means the other way:  they both provide power.  Only one provides data.  

so then my follow up question is... will there be any back feed into the battery pack from the car?  or visa versa, which may cause damage to either?

Comment: @superfry I have absolutely no idea with that kind of Y cable, i've never used such a thing..But i guess you can find out if there is going to be backfeed or not. .See if there is any power coming out of it.. Either snip it and check with a multimeter what is going on there re Volts and current, or get a USB volt/amp metre (very cheap on ebay).

Comment: I'd guess a data port would have some power.. and data only cables would be 5V and very low current (though I haven't had that Y cable or done tests, so I am not absolutely certain re that).  I don't think you want any volts/amps/power going in to your battery pack.  But It's not clear to me what devices you plan to plug on what ends of the cable.. Also what battery pack you have in mind.. I've rarely plugged a USB cable into a battery pack before, so it's hard for me to fully see what you mean.

Comment: Looking at what you want to do.. You want to plug a device into one male end and a device into the other male end.. That seems like something that might not work 'cos one male port is data only so might handle much less current than the other one.  The other aspect of what you are looknig at doing,  two different power sources going into a circuit, doesn't seem right at all.. I'm not electronics guru but maybe it will make a short circuit between the two power sources.

Comment: I am googling a bit now about having two batteries in a circuit,  which is part of what you are doing.. I don't know the ins and outs of it.  That in itself is a tricky electronics question  I suggest you don't go there https://www.quora.com/Is-the-more-dangerous-to-connect-two-batteries-in-series-or-parallel-in-driving-a-load    apparently there is an issue if one weakens, for example.

Comment: @barlop just to clarify... for the y-USB cable, both sides allow equal current to flow.  But only one side is capable of sending data so there's not an issue re: unequal V or A.    The battery pack that I would use is 20,000mAh.  I assume both the car and the battery pack will generate the same voltage (5V).  Yes I believe it is indeed a short circuit since both power sources will have a common node.  Perhaps my question is whether or not the car or the battery pack have safety features to not allow backfeeding. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: @barlop  Not sure that this situation is comparable to simple flashlight batteries since I believe those will have less voltage as they drain while the car or the battery pack voltage remain steady at 5V?

Comment: @superfry that's a good point.. One issue may be that the batteries are unlikely to be exactly the same voltage.. e.g. one source might be 5.1 the other 4.9   There is an electronics.stackexchange.com with some electronicis gurus that may know

Comment: @barlop - The portions of the circuit with regards to USB.  I am an engineer by trade.  As proven by poorly designed Type-C cables, not all USB circuits, are great equal

Answer (score 1):

The Y-Adapter that you linked to is a 2-female to 1-male cable. The description of most of these cables are so poorly translated, I'm not even sure the seller knows what they are used for. I certainly wouldn't trust them with my expensive equipment.

Anyways, I'm going to assume you actually meant to show a 2-male to 1-female Y adapter, as you stated in your question. In any case, I'm going to state the fact that these types of USB cables are only used for providing extra power to high-powered USB devices.

It can be safely assumed that a USB Y cable you purchase will be electrically wired in the following way:

**Combined power (red and black) with separate data (yellow and green).**
[image]

The USB 2.0 specification provides for up to a 500mA current draw. While USB 3.0 allows for up to 900mA. If you have a device that requires more than this amount of current, you can plug both male plugs into two USB ports on the "same" device to provide up to 1000mA and 1800mA respectively.

There are 3 circuits formed in this wiring diagram:

- Male1 to Female
- Male2 to Female
- Male1 to Male2

Any potential energy difference (i.e. Voltage) between Male1 and Male2 as a power source will cause a current to flow between Male1 and Male2 and Female will draw current unequally from Male1 and Male2.

Depending on the power sources hooked up to Male1 or Male2, you may cause any of the following scenarios:

- Male1 may source all the current for the entire circuit, while Male2 contributes nothing or actually draws additional current.
- Vice-verse, Male2 may source all the current for the entire circuit, while Male1 contributes nothing or actually draws additional current.
- Male1 and Male2 will provide current to Female, but they will do so in an unequal manner.
- Either Male1 or Male2 may be overloaded and burn out or shut down.
- Female may not get enough current to power the device.

USB ports do not expect a power source to be on the other end of the connection and may not be wired to handle this. The above issues are mitigated when Male1 and Male2 are plugged in to the "same" device, such as two USB ports on a computer. This is because often times it is the same power supply providing energy to both ports and the potential difference between the two is minimal or non-existent.

You are talking about hooking up a car USB output and a battery powered USB output at the same time. Because no battery chemistry I am aware of provides exactly 5v, you can be sure that both the car and the battery powered USB ports have additional circuitry to control current/charging/voltage regulation, etc. It is also safe to assume that both devices will most likely have different control circuitry. As a result, both ports will supply a different voltage, potentially have different current limits, and will contribute to the above circuit unequally.

Therefore, after all of that, the best answer is that most likely these ports will be unbalanced and there is a high-risk of damaging something or for it to not work as intended. There is, however, a chance that it will all work as intended. The choice is yours to make.

If it were me, I would absolutely not even attempt this. Instead, I would wire my dashcam directly to an "always on" source in the car (i.e. One that bypasses the ignition switch). That source is easily reachable - it is used to keep the memory in the radio, and other circuitry when the ignition is off. Of course, you would need to make sure that supply is regulated to 5v if that is what your camera needs.

Comment: Given that car batteries drain if somebody merely leaves the headlights on,  Or even turning the ignition key a little but to turn on the cigarette lighter charger without turning the car engine on, and charging a phone, can drain the battery leading to the car not turning on.   So if he did access this voltage source, I guess maybe pulling out the car radio and geting access to that power source, then wouldn't it drain his car battery quite a bit? perhaps it's more an issue with an unhealthy car battery. But I wonder how long it'd take to drain even a healthy one.

Comment: Because of conversion from 12v to 5v I will talk about Watt-Hour capacity. A small automotive battery can supply around 540 watts for an hour (45amp @ 12v). Based on some quick research, the highest power dash cam I found was 6 watts. Ignoring small inefficiencies and conversion losses, the camera could run for 90 hours before draining the battery. Depending on the health of the battery and the level of reserve energy needed to start the car, the OP could safely run most dash cams for at least a few days I would guess. But, a shut off switch for extended periods would be best. @barlop

Comment: @Appleoddity thank you very  much for your detailed analytical answer.  I made a mistake in sending the wrong Amazon product link; Yes i meant 1 female to 2 male.  I suspected that what you said might happen.  I wanted to get some more opinions from more knowledgeable persons than I before I screw up expensive electronics.  


Perhaps I can go to a car alarm shop to have such circuitry installed as you recommended.  Is there such thing as a 1-female to 2-male USB cable with a toggle switch?